# Google drive php get file name before download

Tags: php, google-drive-api

Am downloading files from google drive which are images, some are png,jpeg or gif files. These files are uploaded via a google form which i then get the file id via the url from google form responses.
I would like to get the original name or its extension.
Currently am using the following code which works

```
   $response = $service->files->get($file_id, array(
                'alt' => 'media')); //service is the google drive service. file id is drive file id
   $upload_file_url = "/uploads/" . time() . "_image.jpg"; //assigning the file as .jpg 
          
  $outHandle = fopen("myFolder/" . $upload_file_url, "w+");

  while (!$response->getBody()->eof()) {
                fwrite($outHandle, $response->getBody()->read(1024));
   }
  fclose($outHandle);
```

The above works but some images are not jpg. Is it possible to get the $response file name or file extension to handle the non jpg file and save them with the correct extension/s

Comment: I know it is a bit irrelevant, but I have a client uploading images in a google drive account having shared all the folders. How  could I get those images like you did in your question? Could you give me a hint, before you do the code you mentioned? What is $service, any help? thanks

Comment: $service is the google drive service. See the following github gist with the full code:  https://gist.github.com/Geowan/05aebffd66505a1f7701541173d9bfa6

Answer (score 1):

[Files.get()](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get?hl=en) is used to get a file's metadata or content by file id.

- If `alt=media` URL parameter is **NOT INCLUDED** in the request, [Files.get()](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get?hl=en) will return a [Files Resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files#resource) which includes the file name and the file type/mime type.
- If `alt=media` URL parameter is **INCLUDED** in the request, [Files.get()](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get?hl=en) will return the file content

> Note:
>
> If you did not set the `fields` optional query parameter in your request, the response includes a **default** set of fields specific to this method. Default includes the following upon checking the API explorer: `kind`, `id`, `name` and `mimeType`

**Sample Code:**

```
$file = $service->files->get($file_id); 
print "File Name: " . $file->getName();
print "Description: " . $file->getDescription();
print "MIME type: " . $file->getMimeType();

$response = $service->files->get($file_id, array(
                'alt' => 'media'));
```

---

You can check the mimeType to determine whether the file is jpg, png or gif using the following:

- JPEG MimeType = "image/jpeg"
- PNG MimeType = "image/png"
- GIF MimeType = "image/gif"

---

**Reference:**

- [Drive API PHP reference documentation](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/php/latest/index.html)
- [Drive API google-api-php-client-services](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client-services/tree/master/src/Google/Service/Drive)

Comment: By using this am getting an error Call to undefined method GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response::getMimeType(). It must be something to do with guzzle http request been done by google drive api.

Comment: Can you update your working code so I could visualize.

Comment: Here it is on a github gist https://gist.github.com/Geowan/05aebffd66505a1f7701541173d9bfa6.

Comment: The file extractor.php has the $service code while the google drive class initializes google drive in php. I have also included my composer.json with parts related to google drive.

Comment: I mean how do you incorporate the proposed solution in your working code? i did not see the procedure where you get the file's metadata which leads to the error